# Apache receives incorrect method on request. GET instead of POST

Tags: apache, nginx, logging, server, reverse-proxy

I developed a seamless API that accepts request from a server.

Whenever the remote server sends a request to my server by POST, apache logs it like this:

```
31.17.40.128 - - [17/Jun/2021:12:24:26 +0000] "GET /wallet/PS/accept HTTP/1.0" 200 9576 "-" "axios/0.21.1"
```

It logs the request as GET method with content-length:0 while my API is expecting the POST with json data.

The server structure is: nginx (as a reversal proxy) + apache

How is it possible? What can be the cause of the problem? Can it be nginx that rewrites the request somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after N hours i figured it out: this is a CORS problem that breaks request when trying to send it via windows machines.
The fix is to change your apache.conf:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
Header always set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Security-Policy, Location"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "600"
```